# change asp:button to input button

Tags: asp.net, html

Was using an asp: button but had to switch to

```
<input id="SubmitComments" type="button"
```

what are the attributes to add text to the btn on screen. similar to'text' attribute for asp:button

Also: instead of TextMode="MultiLine" rows=5, what can i use?
Ta

Comment: Two different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value='your text'` Attribute for the text of the button.

```
<input id='SubmitComments' name='SubmitComments' type='button' value='your text'/>
```

As for multiline, I assume that is for a text box. Buttons don't hear multiple lines.

Use a `textarea` element for multi line text input.

```
<textarea id='yourTextBoxName' name='yourTextBoxName' rows='5' />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use button in Html as

```
<input type="button" value="Click Here" />      // value= Text to show
```

Submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Click Here to Submit" />
```

Multiline TextBox

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="25" />   // can define rows and columns
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

use `Value` Attribute to add text to your input type button